# Need to pass value from interceptor to handller in spring

Tags: spring

Hey I am new to spring and I need help on below:
I have interceptor with prehandle and posthandle mehtods in it.I want to send some values to handller from interceptor.

suggest any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as:
In your interceptor prehandle method:

```
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            ...
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("attributeName", objectYouWantToPassToHandler);
            ....
            }
```

In your handler handleRequest method:

```
   public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {                

        ....
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        objectYouWantToPassToHandler objectYouWantToPassToHandler = session.getAttribute("attributeName");
        ....
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question ins't clear, sorry. Try start from [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

And, of course, you have to show your code: what you have and what you want to do.